# Retrieve Windows 8 Product Key from mainboard

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, windows-activation

My new laptop came preinstalled with Windows 8. Naively, as I am, I just formatted the harddrive and installed fine old Ubuntu. Now I want to install Windows 8 for dual boot again, but I have no DVD and to download the ISO one needs a product key. That key is not on the back of the laptop anymore but somewhere on the mainboard.

Is there any way to recover the product key from the mainboard using Ubuntu?

Comment: I think you might be out of luck. Perhaps contact the vendor of the laptop you just bought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an ISO for the proper version of Windows 8, just reinstall it and it *should* pick up the key embedded in the BIOS.

Comment: As stated I don't have the ISO and I need my product key to get it :/

Comment: @Gregor Find the iso on torrents and check the SHA1 with MSDN. The key is what makes Windows legal, not the CD.

Comment: Even if you have the product key, where will you download the ISO from? If you don't have a copy of Win8 and it came pre-installed instead of you downloading it as an Upgrade from MS, you'll need to contact the laptop manufacturer for a recovery/install DVD.

Comment: There is a windows 8 Setup tool from Microsoft which lets you download your copy after you enter the product key.

So you think torrenting it wouldn't be illegal since I have a license? If that's how it is, than that's what I'm gonna do.

Comment: "There is a windows 8 Setup tool from Microsoft which lets you download your copy after you enter the product key." - AFAIK that's only for those who used the Upgrade Offer and downloaded Win8 from MS. If you got it pre-installed, I don't think that tool will work for you. As for torrenting Win8, it's illegal (even if you have a valid key) and I did not suggest it.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I was refering to what kinokijuf said.
Hm so that leaves me only with contacting my laptop manufactuer... That might take a while >.<
But I guess the question is answered, thank you!